# How to read or append a specified file without extracting it using python?

Tags: python, zip, feature-extraction

Is it possible to read a file inside a zip folder without extracting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reading**

You could use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module,

```
import zipfile

def read_zip_file(file_path):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path)
    for file_info in z.infolist():
        file = z.open(file_info)
        line_list = file.readlines()
        print line_list
```

**Appending**

```
import zipfile

def append_zip_file(zip_folder_path, file_to_append):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(file_to_append, "a")
    z.write(file_to_append)
    z.close()
```

Basically, you would need to use `ZipFile.extract` to extract anything from the Zip folder. So, any solution that is not using this method is not actually extracting anything.

**EDIT**

In OP particualr case, it seems you have to handle UTF-16 encoding. Therefore, try this code instead,

```
def read_zip_file(filepath):
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath)
    for finfo in zfile.infolist():
        ifile = zfile.open(finfo)
        line_list = ifile.read()
        print line_list.decode("utf-16")
```

Comment: If I use this solution i am not seeing the actual content of the file. The content displayed as [b'\xff\xfe"\x00F\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00L\x00e\x00n\x00g\x00t\x00h\x............................

Comment: @ArockiaRajV What Python version are you using and what is the file extension you're trying to read?

Comment: @ArockiaRajV Glad it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176650/discussion-between-arockia-raj-v-and-scharette).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176704/discussion-between-arockia-raj-v-and-scharette).